# get_queried_object_id in AJAX

Tags: ajax

Can anyone please tell me how to get the get_queried_object_id from the AJAX file?

What I've tried is:

```
$object_id = get_queried_object_id();
print_r($object_id); die();
// Outputs 0

global $wp_query;
$object_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
print_r($object_id); die('');
// Outputs 0
```

As far as I can tell, I won't be able to get the `get_queried_object_id` within the AJAX, so how am I supposed to get it in the right way, please?

Update:
the output for the `global $wp_query;var_dump($wp_query);exit;`

```
["queried_object"]=>
  NULL
  ["queried_object_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["request"]=>
  NULL
  ["posts"]=>
  NULL
  ["post_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_post"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["in_the_loop"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["post"]=>
  NULL
  ["comments"]=>
  NULL
  ["comment_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_comment"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["comment"]=>
  NULL
  ["found_posts"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_comment_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["is_single"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_preview"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_date"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_year"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_month"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_day"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_time"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_author"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_category"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tag"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tax"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_search"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_comment_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_trackback"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_home"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_404"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_embed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_paged"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_admin"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_attachment"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_singular"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_robots"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_posts_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_post_type_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["thumbnails_cached"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=>
  NULL
  ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "query_vars_hash"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "query_vars_changed"
  }
  ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "init_query_flags"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "parse_tax_query"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code. Where is the query coming from & what javascript are you using to access the ajax-endpoint?

Comment: @admcfajn I'm using jquery with post and json; ajax-endpoint isn't an issue;

Comment: So, if you `global $wp_query;var_dump($wp_query);exit;` you're good? You see the query?

Comment: @admcfajn, I'm posting it in the Post, as it says its too many characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's start from trying to understand, what `get_queried_object` function does. According to its [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object):

> Retrieve the currently-queried object. For example:
>
> - if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
> - if you're on a page, it will return the page object
> - if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
> - if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
> - if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object etc.

As you can see, this function returns the object that should be queried for current request based on the URL of this request.

But AJAX calls are other, independent requests. If you use [AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), as you should, then you're creating a request to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` file. So there is no object queried for that request.

If you need the queried object in your AJAX function, then you have to pass it on in the request you make in JS.

Let's say, we're on single post page. The `get_queried_object` function returns that object. And we want to perform some action with AJAX and we need that post object inside that action. In such case you have to:

1. Pass the ID of that queried object to JS script.
2. Use that ID in JS and put it in data that is sent with your AJAX request.
3. Use that data in your AJAX callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Krzysiek!
That's actually exactly what I did, I just wanted to somehow verify/compare that the object id is the same as one passed through JS. So, I guess(from your explanation) that I won't be able to do this. Is this correct, for 100%(as far as you can say, ofc)?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to get ID of object queried in another request. You have to pass it in SESSION or in request itself.